# Android Linear layout and percentage

Tags: android-layout

I want to create layout similar to one attached. The left hand side needs to be scrolled text occupying 75% of screen horizontally. The remaining 25% will consists of few icons stacked vertically and a button that should align at the bottom.

But I can't seem to get the working.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDZel.png

I would appreicate any help in getting this layout stuff right, my current layout looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1.0">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/card_details"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="50"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                android:text="" >
            </TextView>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:minHeight="84dp"
                android:minWidth="84dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<LinearLayout android:gravity="center" android:orientation="horizontal" 
                android:padding="4.0dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/read_id_btn"
                style="@style/PageButton"
                android:layout_width="100dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/read_id" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

~

Answer (score 0):

Try weigth "2" and "1".
Good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This code**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```